# How to get pixel values of an image and store it into an array?

Tags: java, image, pixel

I want to try finding an image within an image. For my "find" method, I would like to take an image and use it to scan and compare the sums of absolute differences with the bigger image.

The smallest SAD would be the exact image that I am using to scan. What I am thinking is to put each pixel value of both images into two separate arrays and compare them via `Math.abs(image1[i][j]-image2[i][j]);`. My only problem is that I do not know how to put each pixel value into an array.

Also, If I only want to compare just the green in the picture. I saw that the Pixel class has a `getGreen();` method. If I want to find the SAD of the green, would `Math.abs(image1.getGreen()-image2.getGreen());` work? I was planning to have 2 nested loops running through each column and row for each image and just find the SAD of the green value.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all the colors of an image into Color[][] like this

```
BufferedImage paintImage = null;
    try {
         paintImage = ImageIO.read(new File ("C://Users/promo.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Color[][] cols = new Color[paintImage.getWidth()][paintImage.getHeight()];
    for(int z = 0;z < paintImage.getWidth();z++){
        for(int a = 0;a < paintImage.getHeight();a++){
            int color = paintImage.getRGB(z, a);

            int  red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            int alpha = (color>>24) & 0xff;
            Color col = new Color(red,green,blue,alpha);
            cols[z][a] = col;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What would I do if I just want to input the red values into the picture array? Also, why is it Color[][] and not int [][]? I just want an array of the red values, would Color[][] do that?

Comment: with color there is getRed() method and also getBlue(), getGreen(), and getAlpha() methods that return int, each Color represents the pixel data for each pixel of an image

Comment: oh, so for my code... I have Picture template = new Picture(a);. Should I use Color template = new Color(a); instead? That way I can just run the template.getRed() and store all red values in the int [][] because essentially, I wanna find all SAD of two int arrays to find the lowest SAD.

Comment: you can do whatever youd like, you know all the details, yeah like you see in the loop that i posted it has int's for the color and even all the different part of the colors, use what youd like :)